# Laravel 5.1 App\Http\Controllers\JWT class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, jwt, json-web-token

I am working with JWT for authentication in my angular - laravel application. Everything is working fine except when the token needs to be generated, I get an error

```
App\Http\Controllers\JWT
```

I've tried adding the following lines in the AuthController :-

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider;
```

and

```
use App\Http\Controllers\JWT;
```

and

```
use JWT;
```

but nothing seems to work

My composer.json :-

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
},
```

AuthController -

```
$payload = [
        'sub' => $user->id,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + (2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    ];
    return JWT::encode($payload, Config::get('app.token_secret'));

public function signup(Request $request){
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->input('displayName');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    /*$user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));*/
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();
    return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user)]);
}
```

Comment: can you show the content of the file on wich you got the error ?

Comment: its in laravel.log - local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\JWT' not found'

Comment: what is the path of the file for the JWT class ?

Comment: A little off context but, its a bad practice to expose `id` to the front-end. You are not utilizing the features the Tymon's JWT provides. You ideally dont need to take a payload. Just go to `config` directory and you will see `JWT.php` and add your `expiry` and `identifier` there

Comment: ok..will take a note. Thanks

Comment: @VishalSh - the payload is not in front end, thats actually AuthController.php file

Comment: Yeah I agree to that but it will be a part of JWT token, which you are going to return to the front-end, which can be easily decoded at websites like http://jwt.io That exposes the `id`. My suggestion would be to use `uuid` in tokens

Comment: ok, got it. Will do. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
JWTAuth;
```

However, `JWTAuth::encode` does not exist, If you must use `encode` method then try this,

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager as JWT;
```

Then you can access `encode` method

```
$customClaims = [
    'sub' => $user->id,
    'iat' => time(),
    'exp' => time() + (2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
];

$payload = app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($customClaims);

return JWT::encode($payload, Config::get('app.token_secret'));
```

Comment: AuthController does not recognize Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth..its showing red line below it..

Comment: this worked for me - I used [ use JWTAuth; use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager as JWT;]

Comment: But I am getting another error now - local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager::encode() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Payload, array given

Comment: This solved it $payload = app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($customClaims);

Comment: yes encode method expects Payload instance, `public function encode(Payload $payload)
    {
        $token = $this->jwt->encode($payload->get());

        return new Token($token);
    }`

Comment: the satellizer_token in my localstorage now is [object Object]...when I console.log it it gives me undefined...I console.log(JSON.stringify(satellizer_token)) it and it says satellizer_token is not defined...is someting wrong....

Comment: should return an object like so `{
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvdmVyaW1hcmtlZC5kZXZcL2FwaVwvdjFcL2F1dGhcL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6IjE0NDk1NzQ3NDQiLCJleHAiOiIxNDQ5NTc4MzQ0IiwibmJmIjoiMTQ0OTU3NDc0NCIsImp0aSI6IjEyYmI1ZmFlNDFkNjIyZjJmOGMzYjg4Nzc1NjZjY2NiIn0.otqIE10UF0CSAsBa6RFB2gf5BMkslUyvLgQh58tn-sM"
}`

Comment: yes, but its not..don't understand y..checking using POSTMAN and it returns blank

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a namespacing issue. I think you want the `JWTAuth` facade.

```
use JWTAuth;  // if added to aliases as the install mentions
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth; // if not aliased
```

**update:** If you have not altered the code inside the class, meaning you still have calls to JWT, you can alias these imports instead and wont have to change the calls to JWT.

```
use JWTAuth as JWT;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth as JWT;
```

Comment: No, not working, this Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth gives error in AuthController.php - I mean a red line.

Comment: what error ? you would have to change how you use it. instead of `JWT::` you would use this as `JWTAuth` ... follow up, did you follow the install instructions ?

Comment: would I have to make changes to kernal.php and config/app.php and then publish..?

Comment: I followed this tutorial for JWT installation - https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: I would follow the install instructions from the packages github wiki. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation

Comment: looks like the tutorials install instructions for that package are correct as well.